# how can i create bar chart with non continuous variable in R?

Tags: r

```
Names=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
Series= c(19.5,18.5,11,13,1,5,6,6)
df=c(Names,Series)

ggplot(df,aes(x= Names,y=Series))+geom_col(position="identity",fill="red")
```

but i have no idea how to make Names to be x-axis since it show weird graph with x axis 0,2.5,5,...
1,2,3,4,5, is not a continuous variable but an indicator
I need x axis to be Names and y axis to be Series
[image: I need x axis to be Names show 1,2,3,4 ... rand y axis to be Series]

Comment: edit output shown in above but change in x axis as 1 ,2 ,3, 4 since it refers to categorical variable but R treat as int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do:

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = factor(Names), y = Series)) + 
    geom_col(position="identity",fill="red")
```

[image]

Comment: how can i change x axis name?

Comment: @SknU Use `gglplot(data.frame(my_name=factor(Names), Series), aes(x=my_name,y=Series))+ ..`